# build dynamic SOQL condition

Tags: soql, query, dynamic-soql

How to build the above query condition dynamically

(i.e.) if same field label like "email" should be in OR conditions remaining labels should in AND condition

eg... `where [((email=:'test@gmail.com')OR(email=:'test_1@gmail.com')) AND ((name=:'testing') OR (name=:'testing_1'))];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I normally do is construct some Set and store there all the possible values you want to compare against.

```
Set<String> setemailsname = new Set<String> {'test@gamil.com','test1@gmail.com'};
Set<String> setNamesName= new Set<String> {'testing','testing_1'};

[... WHERE email IN: setemailsname AND name IN: setNamesname] ;
```

You can set up the values to compair against on Custom labels or custom settings and then add those values into the sets instead of using static values like I put in the sample code, but it was just for exemplification purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that you can use value collections in **pure SOQL** with no need for assistance from Apex. The `IN` operator is the way to go, but it can be used from entirely within the query by wrapping the value collection in parentheses (`()`):

```
WHERE Email IN ('value1', 'value2') AND Name IN ('value3, value4')
```

It takes a bit more care in escaping single quotes, but can yield more portable query strings, which you can then copy to other tools as needed.